# Inflating a ListView from PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-listview, android-adapter

I want to inflate a `ListView` using PHP and MySQL. I have the layouts of the items and I have no idea where to start. How do I infate the `ListView`, set listeners and execute queries to MySQL to update the `ListView`? I also would limit the number of items and load more at the end of the scroll.

Comment: you must first get your data from server (you can use `Json`), then create Custom adapter and set to listView, and for update your List you can use Service, and for understanding that you can see following link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score -1):

So you want to inflate a android listView from PHP? This is not possible. You would have to make a android app fetch the data from your webapp, and render it from there.